# tar without retaining the directory structure

Tags: php, centos, tar

I would like to tar a directory without retaining the directory structure, for example I am tarring like this

```
shell_exec('tar czf '. __DIR__ .'/tmp/'.$entry.'.tar.gz /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/'.$entry);
```

This works fine and correctly but when I open the .tar.gz it is shown like this

[image]

I would like to not retain the directory structure just the folder contents without the directory structure. So like, the .tar.gz contains **/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server1** I just would like to only have the contents of the directory **server1** in the .tar.gz

contents of server1:

[image]

If anyone could be of any help on this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tar -C` to `change directory` before creating the archive:

```
tar cz -C /path/to/dir . -f /path/to/archive.tar.gz
# archive.tar.gz gets contents of /path/to/dir as root entry:
# ./
# ./data.txt
```

If I got your PHP-code correctly, it would be something like:

```
$tar_dir = "/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/$entry";
$archive = __DIR__ . "/tmp/$entry.tar.gz";
shell_exec("tar cz -C $tar_dir . -f $archive");
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way would be to pre-process the tar archive before extracting it. Then you would have several steps:

1. process the `tar` archive, probably using [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/) (probably with `-Remove_Prefix` option); you then could remove any prefix in the tar ball and you'll get new a modified `tar` archive.
2. extract from that new modified archive, using `tar -xf`; you might also pass `-C` to change directory (as suggested by [Grebneke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21348809/841108))
3. Remove the new modified `tar` archive (and perhaps the original one, if needed)

This approach is quite general, since  `tardy` is a quite powerful processor. However, you might need more disk space (potentially twice the space occuped by the archived files, since you probably need the processed tar archive to be uncompressed).